# How to get message from RAML in a Mule message flow

Tags: api, mule, raml

I have created a flow in anypoint studio and using a raml file for invoking REST API. In this particular case I want to get the exact value of respective field specified in my RAML file.

E.g. In the message flow I want to get the exact value like emp_name.

Please help me to understand how can I can I achieve the same:

Below is my raml file

```
#%RAML 0.8
title: EmployeeInfo
version: 1.0
baseUri: http://server/api/{version}
/EmployeeDetails:
  /{emp_name}:
    get: 
      description: Get Employee information
      responses:
         200:
           body:
             application/json:
enter code here
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using APIKIt generated flows in Mule, all URI params will be added as Flow Vars and all Query params will be inboundProperties. So "emp_name" will be available as a flowVar:

```
<logger level="INFO" message="#[flowVars.emp_name]" />
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan for the answer. Yes I am using APIKit generated flow When I used the above code I am getting the following error " the payload is of type byte[]. Could you please tell should I need to use anything in the router mapping for raml? Or how to do it in a flow ? Should I need to use some data mapper ? As I can see in raml the response is of type json.

Answer (score 0):

Better if you can post the logs with full error here, and also your mule config. I doubt that the error is on that logger since it could just log 'null' if not existing.

Answer (score 0):

In the message flow these parameters turns into flow variables . You can directly use the flow variables to get the value you are looking .